# TypeError: endswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bool

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that moves files from the downloads folder to specific folders after being downloaded I'm getting the error above

so i used this simple approach to move files from a source folder which is Downloads to other folders for each type of files, but since i'm new to python i think i'm missing something here !

I tried to change operators.

Here's the full code :

```
from os import scandir, rename
from os.path import splitext, exists, join
from shutil import move
from time import sleep

import logging

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


source_dir = ""
dest_dir_sfx = ""
dest_dir_music = ""
dest_dir_video = ""
dest_dir_image = ""
dest_dir_icon = ""
dest_dir_png = ""
dest_dir_PhotoShop = ""
dest_dir_Vector = ""
dest_dir_doc = ""
dest_dir_word = ""
dest_dir_pdf = ""
dest_dir_ppt = ""
dest_dir_excel = ""
dest_dir_csv = ""
dest_dir_compressed = ""
dest_dir_installs = ""

# ? supported image types
image_extensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".jpe", ".jif", ".jfif", ".jfi", ".png", ".gif", ".webp", ".tiff", ".tif", ".psd", ".raw", ".arw", ".cr2", ".nrw",
                    ".k25", ".bmp", ".dib", ".heif", ".heic", ".ind", ".indd", ".indt", ".jp2", ".j2k", ".jpf", ".jpf", ".jpx", ".jpm", ".mj2", ".svg", ".svgz", ".ai", ".eps", ".ico"]
# ? supported Video types
video_extensions = [".webm", ".mpg", ".mp2", ".mpeg", ".mpe", ".mpv", ".ogg",
                    ".mp4", ".mp4v", ".m4v", ".avi", ".wmv", ".mov", ".qt", ".flv", ".swf", ".avchd"]
# ? supported Audio types
audio_extensions = [".m4a", ".flac", "mp3", ".wav", ".wma", ".aac"]
# ? supported Document types
document_extensions = [".doc", ".docx", ".dotx",".odt",
                       ".pdf", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".csv", ".xlsx", ".xls"]
# ? supported Installs types
installs_extension = [".pkg", ".dmg", ".iso"]
# ? supported Compressed types
compressed_extension = [".arc", ".arj", ".as", ".b64", ".btoa", ".bz", ".bz2", ".cab", ".cpt", ".gz", ".hqx", ".lha", ".lzh", ".mim", ".mme", ".pak", ".pf",
                        ".rar", ".rpm", ".sea", ".sit", ".sitx", ".tar.gz", ".tbz", ".tbz2", ".tgz", ".uu", ".uue", ".z", ".zip", ".zipx", ".zo"] 

def make_unique(dest, name):
    filename, extension = splitext(name)
    counter = 1
    # * IF FILE EXISTS, ADDS NUMBER TO THE END OF THE FILENAME
    while exists(f"{dest}/{name}"):
        name = f"{filename}({str(counter)}){extension}"
        counter += 1

    return name


def move_file(dest, entry, name):
    if exists(f"{dest}/{name}"):
        unique_name = make_unique(dest, name)
        oldName = join(dest, name)
        newName = join(dest, unique_name)
        rename(oldName, newName)
    move(entry, dest)


class MoverHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    # ? THIS FUNCTION WILL RUN WHENEVER THERE IS A CHANGE IN "source_dir"
    # ? .upper is for not missing out on files with uppercase extensions
    def on_modified(self, event):
        with scandir(source_dir) as entries:
            for entry in entries:
                name = entry.name
                self.check_audio_files(entry, name)
                self.check_video_files(entry, name)
                self.check_image_files(entry, name)
                self.check_document_files(entry, name)
                self.check_installs_files(entry, name)
                self.check_compressed_files(entry, name)

    def check_audio_files(self, entry, name):  # * Checks all Audio Files
        for audio_extension in audio_extensions:
            if name.endswith(audio_extension) or name.endswith(audio_extension.upper()):
                if entry.stat().st_size < 10_000_000 or "SFX" in name:  # ? 10Megabytes
                    dest = dest_dir_sfx
                else:
                    dest = dest_dir_music
                move_file(dest, entry, name)
                logging.info(f"Moved audio file: {name}")

    def check_video_files(self, entry, name):  # * Checks all Video Files
        for video_extension in video_extensions:
            if name.endswith(video_extension) or name.endswith(video_extension.upper()):
                move_file(dest_dir_video, entry, name)
                logging.info(f"Moved video file: {name}")

    def check_image_files(self, entry, name):  # * Checks all Image Files
     lower_name = name.lower()
     if lower_name.endswith(image_extensions):
        if lower_name.endswith(".ico" ):
            dest_img = dest_dir_icon

        elif lower_name.endswith(".psd"):
            dest_img = dest_dir_PhotoShop

        elif lower_name.endswith((".ai", ".eps")):
            dest_img = dest_dir_png

        elif lower_name.endswith(".png"):
            dest_img = dest_dir_png

        else:
            dest_img = dest_dir_image
    
        move_file(dest_img, entry, name)
        logging.info(f"Moved image file: {name}")

     else:
        logging.error(f"Not an image file: {name}")

    def check_document_files(self, entry, name):  # * Checks all Document Files
     lower_name2 = name.lower()
     if lower_name2.endswith(document_extensions):
        if   lower_name2.endswith((".doc",".docx", ".dotx")):        
                dest_doc = dest_dir_word

        elif lower_name2.endswith(".pdf"):
                dest_doc = dest_dir_pdf

        elif lower_name2.endswith((".csv", ".xlsx", ".xls")):
                dest_doc = dest_dir_excel

        elif lower_name2.endswith((".ppt", ".pptx",)):
                dest_doc = dest_dir_ppt
       
        else :
             dest_doc = dest_dir_doc

             move_file(dest_doc, entry, name)
             logging.info(f"Moved document file: {name}")
     else:
       logging.error(f"Not an document file: {name}")
   
    def check_installs_files(self, entry, name):
        for installs_extension in installs_extension: 
          if name.endswith(installs_extension) or name.endswith(installs_extension.upper()):
            move_file(dest_dir_installs, entry, name)
            logging.info(f"Moved install file: {name}")

    def check_compressed_files(self, entry, name):
        for compressed_extension in compressed_extension: 
          if name.endswith(compressed_extension) or name.endswith(compressed_extension.upper()):
            move_file(dest_dir_compressed, entry, name)
            logging.info(f"Moved Compressed file: {name}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = source_dir
    event_handler = MoverHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

I'm getting the same error that i had even when i used @Barmar Solution.

Comment: Why do you have `image_extension ==`? It should just be `name.endswith(".ico")`.

Comment: It's also not clear why those `if` conditions are in the loop, since they don't depend on the variable.

Comment: What is the intent of this code? It seems like you want to move a single file to different directories depending on file extension. But the routine is called "check_image_files" and you have a loop for image extensions and you call something called move_file (but with 3 values?) only if the file _doesn't_ have one of your extensions. Very confusing!

Comment: Please post a [mre] (MINIMAL!) and the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because `image_extension == ".ico"` will return a boolean( True or False) but .endswith() takes a string as an argument. So if you want to check if name ends with „.ico“ you can do this:

```
if name.endswith(".ico"):
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `endswith()` must be the string to test as the ending (or a list of strings). You're passing the boolean result of comparing each extension with `image_extension`.

You shouldn't have the `for` loop in the first place, since you don't need to do anything repeatedly. `endswith()` can be given a list of ending strings to test, so you can just use `.endwith(image_extensions)`. Then you can test the specific extensions to get the intended icon.

And the `move_file()` call shouldn't be in the `else:` block, it should be done for any extension.

```
def check_image_files(self, entry, name):  # * Checks all Image Files
    lower_name = name.lower()
    if lower_name.endswith(image_extension):
        if lower_name.endswith(".ico" ):
            dest_img = dest_dir_icon

        elif lower_name.endswith(".psd"):
            dest_img = dest_dir_PhotoShop

        elif lower_name.endswith((".ai", ".eps")):
            dest_img = dest_dir_png

        elif lower_name.endswith(".png"):
            dest_img = dest_dir_png

        else:
            dest_img = dest_dir_image
    
        move_file(dest_img, entry, name)
        logging.info(f"Moved image file: {name}")

    else:
        logging.error(f"Not an image file: {name}")
```